# Animate a ring spinning it around a circle

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to create a CSS animation for a ring to spin around a circle without much success. I searched about to see more or less how I could accomplish that and I came to this:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
}

#loading {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}

.ring {
  animation: ring linear 2s infinite;
}

 @keyframes ring {

   100% {
     transform: rotate3d( 1,1,1,-360deg ) rotate( -360deg ) rotateY( 360deg );
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="loading">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cW9hEgY.gif" class="ring" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dfZJ7FW.gif" class="sphere" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The ring spins, but it's... too random, even for the final effect I have in mind (which will be very random, in way). I tested a lot of combinations and I came to think that it's probably fault of the `rotate3d()`, even more because I couldn't understand much of its documentation on MDN.

I figured that since the ring would be spinning diagonally I could rotate it outside the animation, along with the `animation` declaration, and then only spin it over the Y-axis but the result was even worse:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
}

#loading {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}

.ring {
  animation: ring linear 2s infinite;
  transform: rotate( 120deg );
}

 @keyframes ring {

   100% {
     transform: rotateY( -120deg );
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="loading">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cW9hEgY.gif" class="ring" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dfZJ7FW.gif" class="sphere" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, as you can see, it it stopping before completing a full spin around the little sphere. And I don't want to speedup the animation for this to become less noticeable, I would like to really fix it.

How I accomplish that?

Comment: what animation are you trying to achieve? How should the circle rotate exactly?

Comment: Forgetting the rotation for a moment, the animation would be pretty much a simple `rotateY()`, over and over around the circle. Achieved that, the ring should be put diagonally. I tried **120deg**, but in the real case I may need to adjust that a bit, but keeping the animation like the `rotateY()`, only diagonally. But it appears that when rotating the ring, the Y-axis "isn't vertical anymore"

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your second snippet, you are animating from `rotate(120deg)` to `rotateY(120deg)`. `rotate()` rotates the element on the Z axis, this might be what is confiusing you.

If your aim is just to rotate the element on the Yaxis, you should remove the transform decalration on the `.ring` element like this :

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
}

#loading {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}

.ring {
  animation: ring linear 6s infinite;
  transform:rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(120deg);
}

 @keyframes ring {
   to {  transform:rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(120deg); }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="loading">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cW9hEgY.gif" class="ring" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dfZJ7FW.gif" class="sphere" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I also mede the animation rotate 6 seconds to 360deg so the first frame is the same as last frame and there is no snap at the end of the animation.

Comment: The second snippet was a sorry attempt to get it done after making the ring diagonally oriented. It must be diagonal because there will be other rings spinning together in different positions at same time. Your approach is spinning on the Y-axis, yes, (and here I apologize for the mistake, I should've say X-axis), but it's not diagonal. Here, a [picture](http://i.imgur.com/OOd05zG.gif)

Comment: @user5613506 I have changed the snippet to match your desired output. please check.

Comment: Now I understand what you meant about the Z-axis, but differently of when it wasn't rotated the back and forth movement is way more noticeable. Can it be "infinite", like if it's spinning constant and endlessly?

Comment: @user5613506 there is no back and forth movement. it is an optical illusion as the element is rotating 360deg on the Y axis.

Comment: Now that I watched it for a little while I noticed that, but can it be avoided? I mean, when the animation starts, the shape curves are on `top-left` and `bottom-right` and when they animate over the axis they gradually change to `top-right` and `bottom-left`. The idea is really to make the ring spin around the the circle without change its original position, otherwise they may collide with the corners of the other rings when implemented

Comment: I tried to add more animation points ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9y3r4ub8/1/)) and it seems to be possible, I think I'm just missing the right angles

Comment: @user5613506 Please be clear about your desired output. Right now I am totaly confused at what exact animation you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
}

#loading {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}

.ring {
  animation: ring linear 2s infinite;
}

 @keyframes ring {

   100% {
     transform: rotateY( -360deg );
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="loading">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cW9hEgY.gif" class="ring" />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dfZJ7FW.gif" class="sphere" />
    </div>
</div>
```

`transform: rotate( 120deg );` makes y-axis *not vertical*. You should also have `360deg` for the rotation to complete a whole circle.